# Does ubuntu touch / tizen offer fullscale pc level command line programs and options?

Tags: ubuntu, arm

Android doesn't include full scale PC like command line experience. None of the GNU/Linux command line packages directly run on Android. Few have been ported but vast majority are unsupported.

Ubuntu touch and Tizen look more familiar to GNU/Linux. But do they support the GNU/Linux command line arm binaries, without cross compiling?

Is command line experience on these OS comparable to that of PC ?